# Multiple column Indexes of tables in view joins

Tags: sql-server, indexing, view

Hi I have a view joined with ID which uses customer no in joins. But there's not an index on CustomerNo alone but with ID. Do these joins use the index?

(let me show I believe i failed to explain it)
View is something like this

```
Select T1.CustomerNo, T1.X, T1.Y, T2.Z 
from T1 inner join T2 on T1.Id = T2.Id
```

this view will be used in some dynamic queries and mostly use CustomerNo on joins. On table T1 There's a clustered index on ID and non-clustered index on (ID,CustomerNo)

Do the queries join the view by CustomerNo use this Index or should I add a seperate index on CustomerNo.

Comment: look at the execution plan, that has all the answers needed.

Comment: I don't have the queries. They are generated dinamically. I am asking for general principle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends. The optimizer's choice of index is guided by many factors, including cardinality and selectivity of predicates. It could be that for the same query, but different parameters, optimizer once produces an execution plan that uses index, and the other time not. You should really check the actual plans.

To grab a plan from the cache, use this query:

```
select text, cast(query_plan as xml)
from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
cross apply sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(plan_handle, 0, -1)
-- add a filter on the text column to isolate the interesting queries only
```

---

Moreover, if you're interested which queries used a particular index, this too can be found out from the plan cache (for the cached plans only, of course)

```
declare @IndexName sysname
set @IndexName = 'name_of_the_index';

with xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan' as p)
select 
     db_name(dbid) + '.' + object_schema_name(objectid, dbid) + '.' + object_name(objectid, dbid) AS database_object
     ,iobj.value('@Index','sysname') AS IndexName
     ,qp.query_plan
     ,iobj.query('.') AS IndexUsage
 from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp 
 cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) qp
 cross apply query_plan.nodes('//p:RelOp') IndexScan(scan)
 cross apply scan.nodes('//p:Object') as IndexObject(iobj)
 where dbid = db_id()
 and iobj.value('@Index','nvarchar(max)') = QUOTENAME(@IndexName,'[')
```

This second query could take time and use some resources, be careful.

Comment: Thanks, But I don't have permission to run these on production Enviroment. Queries work as a batch process in the morning, according to user choises on a rule based screen. I believe, under these conditions, adding an extra Index on CustomerNo alone will be the safer aproach?

Comment: It all depends on whether optimizer will push the filters before the joins or not. A half-blind guess would be to create separate indexes on join columns and also on where predicates. (BTW, you can run these queries on test environment as well. Just run your morning batches there)